# Store matrices and perform calculations

Tags: php, matrix

On every request of a webpage I have to multiply a matrix by a vector. The matrix is symmetric and (probably) sparse, with dimensions of approximately 500x500. The vector is a column taken out of another matrix with dimensions of approximately 500x100000. Now my question is how I store the matrices and execute the calculation in an effective way. I would like to do the calculations with php and store the matrices with mysql or on harddrive, but I assume there are better tools for this kind of task.

If you need to know anything further, don't heasitate to ask!

Comment: How sparse are the matrices? This is important to evaluate MySQL storage.

Comment: About 11% of the entries have a nonzero value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so we got a real corner-case here:

- 500x100,000=50,000,000 elements. Depending on the data type, this
  translates to ca. 50M-400M of in-memory representation if we ignore
  sparsity and address by index. The matrix being symmetric reduces this to 25-200M
- A non-zero density of 11% means, that an overhead of 9 Elements for
  sparse adressing is a break even - not really convincing for small
  data types, but might be an option for 64bit data types.

Working from this gives strong argument to a two-tier solution:

- A (shared) "data store server" (MySQL being the one option you
  mentioned)
- and a (maybe PHP) frontend.

Using PHP for a 500x500 matrix multiplication doesn't seem to be a very efficient way to go: Loop overhead is quite high in PHP, so with so little done inside the loop, you might be wasting a bit of performance.

I recommend to go for a slightly different solution: Write your own backend (maybe in C or C#), that

- On startup reads the matrix into memory
- Listens on a (local) socket for commands, e.g. "multiply"
- Executes those commands on the matrix and given data and returns the result

and feed it via PHP. This way you get the processing speed of a compiled language for the core function, while having the simplicity and web-centricity of PHP for the frontend.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. I'll try to go for option two.